# Regex for network service port definitions

Tags: javascript, regex, port, network-service

my collegue and I try to build a Regex (Javascript) to validate an input field for a specific format.
The field should be a comma seperated list of port declarations and could look like this:

> TCP/53,UDP/53,TCP/10-20,UDP/20-30

We tried this regex:

```
/^[TCP/\d+,|UDP/\d+,|TCP/\d+\-\d+,|UDP/\d+\-\d+,]*[TCP/\d+|UDP/\d+|TCP/\d+\-\d+|UDP/\d+\-\d+]$/g
```

the regex matches, but also matches other strings as well, like this one:

> TCP/53UDP53,TCP/10-20UDP20-30

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all those alternations, and the `[` `]` are not used for grouping like that. You can also make the `-` and digits part optional using grouping `(?:...)?`

To match that string format:

```
^(?:TCP|UDP)\/\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,(?:TCP|UDP)\/\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:TCP|UDP)` Match one of the alternatives
- `\/\d+(?:-\d+)?` Match `/` 1+ digits and optionally `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `,(?:TCP|UDP)\/\d+(?:-\d+)?` Match a `,` and repeat the same pattern
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat (If there should be at least 1 comma, change the `*` to `+`)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UhHmee/1)

Comment: great, it works just fine. Thank you for the explanation of the different parts, will definitly look deeper into the regex syntax soon.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: split up the string, use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and a relative simple `RegExp` for testing.

```js
const valid = `TCP/53,UDP/53,TCP/10-20,UDP/20-30`;
const invalid = `TCP/53UDP53,TCP/10-20UDP20-30`;

console.log(`${valid} ok? ${checkInp(valid)}`);
console.log(`${invalid} ok? ${checkInp(invalid)}`);

function checkInp(str) {
  return str.split(`,`)
    .filter(v => /^(TCP|UDP)\/\d+(?:-\d+)*$/.test(v))
    .join(`,`)
    .length === str.length;
}
```